# ActiveAdmin, CSV import, change encoding to cp1251

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, character-encoding, activeadmin

I use ActiveAdmin. ActiveAdmin provides CSV file downloads on the index screen for each resource. How can I change encoding of CSV file to `cp1251` standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby CSV encoding you can do this way..

```
  contents = CSV.generate( your_string.encode("cp1251"))
```

Comment: I do not need to open the file in a particular encoding, I need to generate it.

Comment: post updated.....you have to encode your string before generating to csv using that string

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
  config.csv_options = { col_sep: ';', force_quotes: true, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1', encoding_options: {invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?'}}
```